# cell formatting issue with jqGrid

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and am having an issue with one cells data.  The contents of the cell should be '3 - Minor' but it's trying to perform a math calculation and returning NaN for the cell.  Is there a way to tell jqGrid these are the contents and not to perform the math?

I've tried quoting, double qouting, etc but am not having any luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set `formatter: 'string'` on your colOptions as per the documentation:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

If so, please post the options so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  I had it set to number and never thought to check...Thanks!

Comment: np :) jqGrid is really cool but can be a pain to get used to at first.